# PHP: Get last directory name from path

Tags: php, trim

I am writing one function for getting some different database query. Now things are going well but only need to get last directory name from defined path.

```
$qa_path=site_root('/learnphp/docs/');
```

I wan to get only `docs` from above path. Here site_root is nothing but `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` So how can I get only `docs` ?

Thanks

Comment: see: http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php

Comment: Thanks but the file may or may not in the same directory. I mean just asking as not so experienced.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Easiest way would be to use `basename($yourpath)` as you can see here: http://php.net/basename

Comment: ah this is most easiest solution i found. just quick question if there will be 3 or 4 sub level of direction will it still get last directory name?

Comment: Yes. Always the last name part of any path. No matter how many levels deep it is. It will either return the deepest directory or the filename, if one is present.

Comment: This is perfect and your answer deserve to be selected answer. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 32):

Provided answer doesn't work if your string contains the file at the end, like :

```
basename('/home/mypath/test.zip');
```

gives

```
test.zip
```

So if your string contains the file, don't forget to **dirname** it first

```
basename(dirname('/home/mypath/test.zip'));
```

gives

```
mypath
```

Answer (score 6):

This is the easiest way:

```
<?php
  echo basename(getcwd());
?>
```

getcwd() = give your full directory path
basename() = give you last directory

Answer (score 2):

Try `explode('/', '/learnphp/docs/')`
to split the string into array locations. Then fetch the last location.

Here is more info:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Comment: Doesn't deserve a down vote as it is a valid solution: just not the best one.

Comment: This is a valid answer. It shouldn't be voted down because you think there may be a "better" way.

Comment: Thank you. Yeah, basename seems like a "better" way but this should work as well :)

Comment: Elaborating on the downvote: This is not an answer in itself, this will return an array object that has to be handled with additional logic, which is not supplied. There are similar answers that do provide this bit of logic.

Comment: if your array is called $result.

$result[$count($result)-1];

Answer (score 1):

you can use this simple snippet:

```
$qa_path=site_root('/learnphp/docs/');
$qa_path = explode("/", $qa_path);
$qa_path = $qa_path[count($qa_path) - 1];
```

Comment: This is not giving any output

Comment: you're right because of the "/" at the end of the string, try using the basename() method suggested by Till Helge Helwig that is a smarter solution

Answer (score 1):

```
$qa_path=explode('/', '/learnphp/docs/');
echo $qa_path[2]; // output docs
```

Comment: but what if there will be more than three directory in path. This array will get always second number directory. Correct?

Comment: SO say for example if anyone else use this function than they have to go manually and have to modify this. Which is not ideal. I want some solution where it will automatically get last directory

Comment: it same what @wezzy said you $qa_path = $qa_path[count($qa_path) - 1];

Answer (score 1):

This will help you

```
$qa_path=site_root('/learnphp/docs/');
$q_path = explode ("/", $qa_path);
$lastV =  end($q_path);
```

Answer (score 1):

This gives you the current directory name:

`echo basename(dirname(__FILE__));`