# preg_replace - return everything to the second slash from the end of the line

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have string `/fsd/fdstr/rtgd/file/upload/file.png`.

I need to return from this string only `/upload/file.png` using function `preg_replace`.

My `preg_replace("/.*\/(.*)/", '/$1', $fullPath, -1)` return only `/file.png`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use the direct approach and implement what you are actually looking for?

This should be very easy to read later:

```
<?php
var_dump(
  preg_replace('|^.*(/[^/]+/[^/]+)$|', '$1', "/fsd/fdstr/rtgd/file/upload/file.png", -1)
);
```

The output obviously is:

```
string(16) "/upload/file.png"
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative using filesystem/path functions (which imho feels more readable than a regex):

```
$path = '/fsd/fdstr/rtgd/file/upload/file.png';

$folder = dirname($path);
$fileName = basename($path);

$result = '/' . basename($folder) . '/' . $fileName;
```

**Demo: https://3v4l.org/YblcW**

Comment: Great advice Jeto.  This is the most appropriate tool for the job.  Found elsewhere like: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26778823/2943403

Answer (score 0):

`((?:\/[^\/\n]*){2})$`

This regex should work - it captures a frontslash, and then any amount of non-frontslash, non-newline text. This repeats twice, and is followed by the end of the line.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pQwFFW/1/)

Answer (score 0):

check this one may help you

```
(\/\w+\/\w+\.\w{3,4})$
```

we add `$` at the end of regex expression to verify from the end not the beginning

here is a [demo](https://regex101.com/r/EGOx6z/2)

Answer (score 0):

You asked for a `preg_replace` solution, however it could be approached in different ways too:

```
$string = '/fsd/fdstr/rtgd/file/upload/file.png';
```

Working with array functions: explode the string into an array then extract the last two items then glue them together.

```
print '/' . implode('/', array_slice(explode('/', $string), -2));
```

or with string functions: find the penultimate occurence of `/` then extract all characters until the end.

```
print substr($string, strrpos(substr($string, 0, strrpos($string, '/')), '/'));
```

both gives the result: `/upload/file.png`